# RDP into VM without an OS

Tags: ubuntu, rdp, virtualbox

Is it possible to RDP into a Virtualbox VM in order to install an OS on it? So in other words is it possible to RDP into a Virtualbox VM that has no OS installed yet?

I have a headless ubuntu server and I have Virtualbox installed on it. I created a VM and I would like to install Ubuntu on this VM. I start the VM, I have selected to enable remote display.

But I am unable to connect to it from my Windows 11 machine using RDP.

For network mode I have tried NAT Network and also Bridged Mode.

For RDP address I have tried both the IP number of the physical server as well as the server of the actual VM (in Bridged Mode).

I must be missing something.

**Update:**

Yes RDP enabled on the VM.

Firewall ports open on iptables.

**Update 2:**

```
vboxmanage showvminfo "ubuntucraft"
Name:                        ubuntucraft
Groups:                      /
Guest OS:                    Debian (64-bit)
UUID:                        c37b7713-aae0-4ded-99e7-f96f55f3be49
Config file:                 /home/user/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntucraft/ubuntucraft.vbox
Snapshot folder:             /home/user/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntucraft/Snapshots
Log folder:                  /home/user/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntucraft/Logs
Hardware UUID:               c37b7713-aae0-4ded-99e7-f96f55f3be49
Memory size:                 2535MB
Page Fusion:                 disabled
VRAM size:                   84MB
CPU exec cap:                100%
HPET:                        disabled
CPUProfile:                  host
Chipset:                     piix3
Firmware:                    BIOS
Number of CPUs:              1
PAE:                         disabled
Long Mode:                   enabled
Triple Fault Reset:          disabled
APIC:                        enabled
X2APIC:                      enabled
Nested VT-x/AMD-V:           disabled
CPUID Portability Level:     0
CPUID overrides:             None
Boot menu mode:              message and menu
Boot Device 1:               DVD
Boot Device 2:               HardDisk
Boot Device 3:               Not Assigned
Boot Device 4:               Not Assigned
ACPI:                        enabled
IOAPIC:                      enabled
BIOS APIC mode:              APIC
Time offset:                 0ms
RTC:                         UTC
Hardware Virtualization:     enabled
Nested Paging:               enabled
Large Pages:                 disabled
VT-x VPID:                   enabled
VT-x Unrestricted Exec.:     enabled
Paravirt. Provider:          Default
Effective Paravirt. Prov.:   KVM
State:                       running (since 2022-06-07T09:42:49.884000000)
Graphics Controller:         VMSVGA
Monitor count:               1
3D Acceleration:             disabled
2D Video Acceleration:       disabled
Teleporter Enabled:          disabled
Teleporter Port:             0
Teleporter Address:
Teleporter Password:
Tracing Enabled:             disabled
Allow Tracing to Access VM:  disabled
Tracing Configuration:
Autostart Enabled:           disabled
Autostart Delay:             0
Default Frontend:
VM process priority:         default
Storage Controller Name (0):            SATA
Storage Controller Type (0):            IntelAhci
Storage Controller Instance Number (0): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (0):  30
Storage Controller Port Count (0):      1
Storage Controller Bootable (0):        on
Storage Controller Name (1):            IDE
Storage Controller Type (1):            PIIX4
Storage Controller Instance Number (1): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (1):  2
Storage Controller Port Count (1):      2
Storage Controller Bootable (1):        on
SATA (0, 0): /home/user/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntucraft/ubuntucraft.vdi (UUID: 7b02b273-b4a5-476b-bf8e-55da955a083c)
IDE (1, 0): /mnt/raiddisk/public_html/craft/ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso (UUID: 5c565295-d88e-4a80-81f7-3995447a54a1)
NIC 1:                       MAC: 080027D959D8, Attachment: Bridged Interface 'eth0', Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: allow-all, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 2:                       disabled
NIC 3:                       disabled
NIC 4:                       disabled
NIC 5:                       disabled
NIC 6:                       disabled
NIC 7:                       disabled
NIC 8:                       disabled
Pointing Device:             PS/2 Mouse
Keyboard Device:             PS/2 Keyboard
UART 1:                      disabled
UART 2:                      disabled
UART 3:                      disabled
UART 4:                      disabled
LPT 1:                       disabled
LPT 2:                       disabled
Audio:                       enabled (Driver: ALSA, Controller: AC97, Codec: STAC9700)
Audio playback:              disabled
Audio capture:               disabled
Clipboard Mode:              disabled
Drag and drop Mode:          disabled
Session name:                headless
Video mode:                  800x600x32 at 0,0 enabled
VRDE:                        enabled (Address 127.0.0.1, Ports 9000-9100, MultiConn: off, ReuseSingleConn: off, Authentication type: null)
VRDE port:                   9000
Video redirection:           disabled
VRDE property               : TCP/Ports  = "9000-9100"
VRDE property               : TCP/Address = "127.0.0.1"
VRDE property               : VideoChannel/Enabled = <not set>
VRDE property               : VideoChannel/Quality = <not set>
VRDE property               : VideoChannel/DownscaleProtection = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableDisplay = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableInput = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableAudio = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableUSB = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableClipboard = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableUpstreamAudio = <not set>
VRDE property               : Client/DisableRDPDR = <not set>
VRDE property               : H3DRedirect/Enabled = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/Method = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/ServerCertificate = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/ServerPrivateKey = <not set>
VRDE property               : Security/CACertificate = <not set>
VRDE property               : Audio/RateCorrectionMode = <not set>
VRDE property               : Audio/LogPath = <not set>
OHCI USB:                    disabled
EHCI USB:                    disabled
xHCI USB:                    disabled

USB Device Filters:

<none>

Available remote USB devices:

<none>

Currently Attached USB Devices:

<none>

Bandwidth groups:  <none>

Shared folders:<none>

VRDE Connection:             not active
Clients so far:              0

Capturing:                   not active
Capture audio:               not active
Capture screens:             0
Capture file:                /home/user/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntucraft/ubuntucraft.webm
Capture dimensions:          1024x768
Capture rate:                512kbps
Capture FPS:                 25kbps
Capture options:

Guest:

Configured memory balloon size: 0MB
OS type:                     Linux26_64
Additions run level:         1
Additions version:           6.0.0 r127566

Guest Facilities:

Facility "VirtualBox Base Driver": active/running (last update: 2022/06/07 09:43:50 UTC)
Facility "Seamless Mode": not active (last update: 2022/06/07 09:43:50 UTC)
Facility "Graphics Mode": not active (last update: 2022/06/07 09:43:50 UTC)
```

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html)? Is RDP enabled? Does your firewall allow incoming RDP?

Comment: Yes RDP enabled and firewall ports open. That's why I am kind of stumped by this.

Comment: Please edit your question to add a diagram of the network containing the host, guest, and your RDP client; `VBoxManage showvminfo` output for the guest containing the VRDP port; and the configuration for your RDP client, such as the mstsc command.    https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#rdp-viewers

Comment: I have added the showvminfo for the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into the properties of the `.vbox` file of the VM the following setting was found:

```
<Property name="TCP/Address" value="127.0.0.1"/>
```

This prevents connections to the VM from anywhere other than localhost.

Once I cleared this setting I was able to RDP to the VM. To clear the setting run this:

```
vboxmanage modifyvm "VM name" --vrdeaddress ""
```